# Cant POST XML over cURL in Unix

Tags: http, unix, iis, post, curl

I am trying to submit a HTTP POST request into a web server that runs IIS.

```
curl -X  POST -d
```

but I am getting an HTML page definition in return.

I have looked and didn't find any match, your support will be appreciated.

Comment: So what is the problem? An html document is a very typical result of a http post request to a server.

Comment: i m getting an HTML page definition, and my request is not been submitted.  i should receive an http response. but i m getting hTTP Page code

Comment: How do you know your data has not been submitted? As long as you don't specify the information you have here there is little we can do for you... What error does `curl` produce, did you even check? And you certainly get an http response, as least as you request an http url. How else do you think that `html page definition` reaches your client, if not by means of an http response. And, sorry, but I have no idea what you mean with a `hTTP Page code`...